# Как поменять шрифт у всех виджетов Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, шрифты

Требуется изменить шрифт у всех виджетов в программе на `Tkinter`, знаю что на `Python 2.7` это было как-то возможно(ссылка в конце вопроса), но данный метод не работает для `Python 3.8.1`.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как одним махом поменять шрифт у всех виджетов?

### Ссылка:

[Изменить шрифт по умолчанию в Python Tkinter](https://overcoder.net/q/303539/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-python-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, правда меняется не весь шрифт, но хотябы большая часть.

```
import tkinter.font as tkFont

[....]

default_font = tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
default_font.configure(size=48)

[.....]

 root.option_add('*Font', default_font)
```

В данном примере `[.....]` пропущенный код

`root.add_option('*Font', default_font)` лучше ставить сразу после создания основного окна(`tkinter.Tk()`) таким образом шрифт будет меняться у всех виджетов, которые использую  `TkDefaultFont`